# update database mysql with a comma seperated value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hello all i have a database where i need to update its one of the fields with a comma separated value.
exactly i need to do is something like ..
say the value in the field is 1,3,4,6,77,87
and i need to add 22 to this field so that after update it should look like  1,3,4,6,77,87,22

i dont know how to do this??
 the present way to add the number is like

```
update tablename set tags=tags+new value where id=2;
```

this code is good for adding of numbers

any help please

Comment: DON'T DO IT!!! NORMALIZE your database... and `+` is for addition (you know, like `1 + 2 is 3` as they taught you in school, so why would you expect to use it for concatenation (damn javascript for corrupting the minds of youth)

Comment: i did't used it i said that this is the query used for addition for numbers but for concatenation i dont' know .read the question again

Answer (score 1):

this is not good idea but if you want do it try this

```
     update tablename set tags= Concat(tags , ',22') where id=2;
```

if this 22 is in a variable then use this

```
  update tablename set tags= Concat(tags , ',' ,'$var') where id=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn=IFNULL (CONCAT( myColumn, ',',  'mydata'), 'mydata') WHERE ID=1
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONCAT` function:

```
UPDATE tablename set tags = CONCAT(tags, ',' , newvalue) where id=2;
```